# How to load content with AJAX in pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, pagination

When writing a gallery faced with a problem.
There is pagination for the gallery. Each page should be different picture.
As with the aid of AJAX upload new content to the gallery when switching pages?
I would be grateful for an example!

```html
<!-- Pagination -->
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="disabled">
        <a href="#">
                       «
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
                     1 
                      <span class="sr-only">
                        (current)
                      </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                     2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                     3
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                     4
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                     5
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
                     »
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 id="galleryTitel">
                            Your work
                        </h1>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a title="Image 1" href="#">
          <img class="thumbnail img-responsive center-block" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/30ufot0.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a title="Image 2" href="#">
          <img class="thumbnail img-responsive center-block" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/30ufot0.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a title="Image 3" href="#">
          <img class="thumbnail img-responsive center-block" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/30ufot0.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a title="Image 4" href="#">
          <img class="thumbnail img-responsive center-block" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/30ufot0.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For example: on the first page , we have 4 photos, we go to another page already there other 4 photo .

Comment: So you want to have different pictures for every page? Are the pages html pages or are they changed with javascript(like angular or Ember or any other single page app library)

Comment: Content on the page should be changed with JavaScript. Just upload new photos when switching pagination.

Comment: What is changing the code, are you asking us to provide you with that?

Comment: An example of how to use Ajax to load new content on the main page, switching pagination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93389/discussion-between-olavi-sau-and-a-fox).

Answer (score 0):

To change the images you simply have to change their src; As I see you have a couple of links.

```
  var img1 = document.querySelector('YOURIMGID/CLASS');
  var img2 = document.querySelector('YOURIMGID/CLASS');
  var img3 = document.querySelector('YOURIMGID/CLASS');
  var img4 = document.querySelector('YOURIMGID/CLASS');
  document.querySelector('YOURLINKID/CLASS').onclick = function() {
        img1.src = "YOURNEWSRC";
        img2.src = "YOURNEWSRC";
        img3.src = "YOURNEWSRC";
        img4.src = "YOURNEWSRC";
  }
```